# Find a point on the opposite site of another point

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, linear-algebra, point

Given two 2D points (p1 and p2), I need find a point (p3) that (from the perspective of p1) is on the other side of p2 and at the same time it needs to have a given distance to p2.

It could look like this with a bigger given distance:

```
  ^
  |
  | p1      
  |         p2 
  |     
  |                         p3
<-|---------------------------->
  v
```

Or like this with a smaller given distance:

```
  ^
  |
  |
  |    p3
  |  p2   
  |p1
<-|---------------------------->
  v
```

How can I calculate this point (p3)?

My language of choice is JavaScript, but I'm not strictly asking for a JavaScript answer. If you can explain it in a way that is translatable into code or if you write pseudo code that would be just fine.

This was my last attempt (obviously this would not work):

```
calculate_point_on_other_side_of_p2(p1, p2, distance_p2_to_p3) {
    deltaX = p1.x-p2.x
    deltaY = p1.y-p2.y
    distance_p1_to_p2 = sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY)
    if (deltaX < 0)
        p3.x = p2.x+distance_p2_to_p3 
    else
        p3.x = p1.x-distance_p2_to_p3

    if (deltaY < 0)
        p3.y = p2.y+distance_p2_to_p3
    else
        p3.y = p1.y-distance_p2_to_p3
    return p3
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to take the square root of distance_p1_to_p2?

Comment: Yes, of course. Corrected that.

Comment: I think in your else statement, you need to do `p3.x = p2.x-distance_p2_to_p3` and `p3.y = p2.y-distance_p2_to_p3`

Comment: i.e. subtract from p2, not p1

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. but adding/substracting distance_p2_to_p3 on both x and y can't be the solution anyway.

Comment: are p1 p2 and p3 on the same line?

Comment: Yes, they have to be on the same theoretical straight line

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy problem if you understand how 2D vectors work.

Calculate the unit vector from p1 to p2:

```
(nx, ny) = ((p2x - p1x)*i + (p2y-p1y)*j)/sqrt((p2x-p1x)^2 + (p2y-p1y)^2)
```

Where i and j are unit vectors in the x and y directions, respectively.

Now you can calculate (p3x, p3y) at any distance d from p1:

```
(p3x, p3y) = (p1x, p1y) + (d*nx, d*ny)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note minus sign because deltas are components of vector from p2 to p1 but **p2p3** is anticollinear to **p2p1**

```
calculate_point_on_other_side_of_p2(p1, p2, distance_p2_to_p3) {
    deltaX = p1.x-p2.x
    deltaY = p1.y-p2.y
    distance_p1_to_p2 = sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY)
    scale = distance_p2_to_p3 / distance_p1_to_p2 
    p3.x = p2.x - deltaX * scale
    p3.y = p2.y - deltaY * scale
    return p3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One version of the correct algorithm would be as follows (this isn't even pseudocode, but should explain what to do):

- work out the distance between p1 and p2 (use pythag)
- divide the given distance (distance_p2_to_p3) by that
- for each of the x and y co-ordinates, add on deltaX (resp deltaY) multiplied by that ratio

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume all three lines are in a line. Then the slope is `deltaY/deltaX`. If p3 is `x` away from p2 horizontally, then it is `deltaY/deltaX * x` away from p2 vertically. `distance_p2_to_p3^2 = x^2 + (deltaY/deltaX * x)^2`, solve for `x`. Then add/subtract `x` from `p2.x` and add.subtract `deltaY/deltaX * x` from p2.y.

Comment: Using slopes usually is wrong approach in computer geometry (just imagine vertical line)

Comment: @MBo good point. I guess we can take care of the edge case before computing the slope, but I like your answer of using ratio